# How to find the basis of a coordinate vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, change-of-basis

If I am given a coordinate [A] and a matrix for A, how am I supposed to find a basis for A. I know how to do the first part, but not sure about the second.

[image]

Comment: $[A]_\varepsilon$ is not a standard notation. I don't know what it means.

Comment: @Andrei Probably $\mathcal E$ refers to some kind of standard basis.

Comment: Thanks @BenGrossmann. Now it makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

All you need is to find 4 independent matrices such that the sum is $A$. The trivial way to do it is to start with the null matrix and add one of the elements of $A$:
$$\mathcal A=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}3&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\-1&0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}\right\}$$

Comment: I was just typing this exact same answer. Kudos for speed.

Comment: Ohhh that makes sense. Thank you!